# Providing a way to sort one's favorites by "date added"?

Tags: support, bookmarks

It is nice to have so many ways of filtering and sorting the thousands of threads in MO. So there I go, and my list of favorites becomes longer and longer. Most often I obviously add rather recent threads, but sometimes old ones. I can of course sort them by date, but it would be helpful to have the additional possibility of **sorting them by the date *when I added them***. Some old topics may become "obsolete" for me (how can such a thing exist in mathematics? obsolete? well you guess what I mean), while others contain useful references or (why not) questions for further research "some day when I'll have time" - or they are just so beautiful that I want to keep them 'forever'.

At a time when I was very active on Mathlinks, I used to keep my own text file with links to the most interesting ones of my numerous favorites, naturally in the order I encountered them. But thus they are not nicely displayed as a list.

In a web browser, there is the possibility of creating subfolders in the 'favorites' folder. I would not ask for such a feature in MO and the associated sites, but knowing that the internet has such a good memory, I guess that the information about when a user has added a favorite is kept somewhere, similarly to the "edit history", and even if not: why not implement that from now on? It should not be complicated to make such an option available as another tab.

Of course, that should only concern one's own favorites. Even though it is often interesting (as many of you will certainly confirm) to look at the favorites of other users, I would not want to become a "big brother" to somebody else by looking up *when* he as added a certain one of his favorites.

Comment: I think you can go to your profile, click _favorites_ , and then choos the _added_ link above the list of your favorite questions to get them sorted in accordance with when you added them, if I am not wrong ...

Comment: @Dilaton: oh, that's nice. I hadn't noticed that!

Answer (score 4):

In the meantime, the whole system of bookmarks on Stack Exchange was revamped and they are now called saves, you can find links to posts with more details [in the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/saves/info).

In particular, now you can use the things which you've mentioned in your question:

- You have several options how to sort [your saves](https://mathoverflow.net/users/saves/current) - one of them is by the date added.
- You can also organize your saves into several lists.

Answer (score 3):

As Dilaton notes in [comments](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1241/providing-a-way-to-sort-ones-favorites-by-date-added#comment5670_1241), yes — this is possible through your profile. There were also some user scripts on [Stackapps](http://stackapps.com) that added more functionality to favorites (letting you note why you made something a favorite using local storage), but I can't for some reason locate the specific apps now.

Re-tagging this as [support](/questions/tagged/support) since it's an existing feature.